# How to move the last digit to the first position in a number in C

Tags: c, loops

I've been trying to put the last digit to the first place and leave all other numbers as they are using the loops, but I can't figure it out.

It should be like this for example 1234 => 4123 Thank you.
I've come up this far, but i cant figure out the code how to put the last digit i found with % 10 in the first position of a number.

```c
{
 
int number;
        
     scanf ("%d", &number);
        
        lastDigit = number % 10;
        
        number =
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is quite a bit missing in that snippet. You should at least provide some more complete code. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.

Comment: Also please format your code properly, jusr like the samples in your learning material.

Comment: "leave all other numbers as they are" That's not what happens in your example. The order is mantained, but they "shift" to the right. Now, note that to get 123 from 1234 you just have to /10 and that to, say obtain 40 from 4,  you just have to *10...

Comment: `scanf` is reading the input as a string and converting it to an integer.  You should just leave it as a string and manipulate it that way.

Comment: You've got the last digit; you can easily get the rest of the digits with division.  You then need to work out how many digits are in the rest, multiplying the 'last' digit by 10 repeatedly.  Then add the multiplied digit to the rest.  Write that code in a function separate from `main()`.  Call it repeatedly from `main()`.  If the function signature is `unsigned rotate(unsigned u);`, then `int main(void) { unsigned u; while (scanf("%u", &u) == 1) printf("%u --> %u\n", u, rotate(u)); return 0; }` works as the test harness.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below .

```
int res = 0, tmp, number ,lastDigit ;


     scanf ("%d", &number);
     tmp = number;
     lastDigit = number % 10;
     while(tmp /=10)
        lastDigit =  lastDigit * 10 ;

     res =  lastDigit  + number/10 ;
```